# React : {-} is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs

**Error** message:

```
  Line 16:18:  'username' is not defined  no-undef

  Line 20:18:  'imageUrl' is not defined  no-undef

  Line 22:49:  'username' is not defined  no-undef

  Line 22:76:  'caption' is not defined   no-undef
```

How I call `Post` component:

```
<Post username="elitorbi" caption="something in here" imageUrl="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-800,height-600,resizemode-75,imgsize-3918697,pt-32,y_pad-40/67586673.jpg"/>
  
<Post username="elitorbi" caption= "this is a caption" imageUrl="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/fe1e34da640c5c56ed16f76ce6f994fa9343d09d/0_174_3408_2046/master/3408.jpgwidth=1200&height=900&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=0d3f33fb6aa6e0154b7713a00454c83d"/>
```

definition:

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react'
    import './post.css'
    import './App.js'
    import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar"
    
    
    function Post() {
        return (
            <div className="post">
                <div className="post__header">
                <Avatar
                    className="post__avatar"
                    alt= 'elitorbi'
                    src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
                ></Avatar>
                <h3>**{username}**</h3>
                </div>
                <img
                className = "post__image" 
                src={imageUrl} />
                
                <h4 className="post__text"><strong>{username}</strong><n> </n>{caption}</h4>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Post
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [component's `props`](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper):

```
function Post(props) {
  const { username, imageUrl, caption } = props;
  return ...
}
```